# The Media query is not changing the font size

Tags: html, css

media query is not changing the font from 20px to 15px idk. there is no override thats the only one media query in the code till now.

```
article .quote{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 7%;
}
@media all and (max-width:1000px){
  .quote{
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `article .quote` in the media query too, if that doesn't work provide codepen

Comment: Strange... not optimal but you can add `!important`

Comment: Please provide the HTML on which this code acts as well; a [mre] would be perfect, using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) if possible.

Comment: @Ankit code works I don't see any issues, most probably the font is too small to differentiate try changing the font size and see the difference. https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/b2txyv4r/80/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some minor issues but this should now work

```css
article.quote{
  font-size: 80px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 7%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  article.quote{
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<article class='quote'>some text</article>
```

```css
article .quote{
  font-size: 80px;
  color: blue;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 7%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  article .quote{
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<article >
   <section class='quote'>some text</section>
</article>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you added `*/` after the `left: 7%;`?

Comment: just a typo, sorry

Comment: Is there a reason you have `article.quote` instead of `article .quote` like in the question?

Comment: yes! either just use .quote or article or article.quote

Comment: I meant you assumed the html structure, OP hasn't provided one. You do know the difference between `article.quote` and `article .quote`, right?

Comment: true, but we do know that what he's doing isn't working.

Comment: Ideally one would wait for clarity from OP

Comment: well, when he/she provides clarity we can update the answer

Comment: Sure thing :) Psst..watch your pronouns!

Comment: No, we close questions that are not clear, we don't answer questions with guesses.

Comment: I've done my part..

Comment: It works as is: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/b2txyv4r/80/

Comment: thanks guys working :)